# Convert XFA based forms to HTML

Tags: html, forms, xfa

Is there a tool or converter available that can transform my [XFA](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/xml/index_arch.html) based forms/documents over to HTML (preserving the look and feel of the form)?

I'm looking to provide the capability to render such forms over tablets and other devices, using HTML.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try idrsolutions pdftohtml convertor which is able to display xfa based pdfs ; you can try their online converter tool [here](https://www.idrsolutions.com/online-pdf-to-html5-converter/)

Comment: its not a all worth  its a waste